# Equivalent of this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").toURI() from within a Jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources, classloader

I'm trying to achieve a way to obtain the base path of the current classloader when runnning from within a jar.

I mean programatically, I already know it should have the shape of "jarPath+jarFile.jar!/"

Unlike file system's call, getResource(".") or .getResource("/") do not work from inside the jar.

Ideally it should be an abstract solution for any file provider, so something like:

```
Path BASE_PATH = Paths.get(...getResource("").toURI())
```

which could return the correct root path for both jars and file system so I can use relative urls to my resources without having to do any conditional statements and url manual string parsing/build.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "root path" within a jar, since it's not part of the filesystem. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you're after relative paths for resources, what's wrong with `SomeClass.class.getResource("foo.jpg")`, which loads the foo.jpg file from the same package as `SomeClass`? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Reading is not a problem, as I specify the resource in the path,  but I need to list/write to the base dir as well and I don't want to do getResource("com").getPaarent() smell whic is error prone ultimately

Comment: @user1352530 resources stored in jar files don't have "directories". If the resource is kept in a jar, then you need to get the directory that the jar is stored in and use that as your information, rather than relying exclusively on what getResource() returns.

Comment: Well I can use same code for both situations (jar/fs) when reading folder input/resource.txt by means of Paths and Files NIO classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find out the path of the jar and or target folder containing you class or any resource by using this code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ClassPathUtils {

  public static String getBasePath(String jarPath) {
    String path = getJarPathFromClass(jarPath);
    if (path == null) {
      return null;
    }

    if (path.startsWith("jar:")) {
      path = path.substring("jar:".length());
    }
    if (path.startsWith("file:")) {
      path = path.substring("file:".length());
    }
    if (path.endsWith(jarPath)) {
      path = path.substring(0, path.length()-jarPath.length());
    }

    return path;
  }
  public static String getBasePath(Class clazz) {
    return getBasePath(classNameDotClass(clazz));
  }
  private static String classNameDotClass(Class clazz) {
    return clazz.getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class";
  }
  private static String getJarPathFromClass(String resource) {
    final URL url = ClassPathUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resource);
    return url == null ? null : url.toString();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //System.out.println(Paths.get(ClassPathUtils.getBasePath("."))); // doesn't work in a jar
    System.out.println(Paths.get(ClassPathUtils.getBasePath(ClassPathUtils.class)));

    System.out.println(Paths.get(ClassPathUtils.getBasePath("fonts/atcitadelscript.ttf"))); // any classpath resource

    System.out.println(Paths.get(ClassPathUtils.getBasePath(String.class))); // actually finds rt.jar

  }
}
```

If you run this code from your IDE, or from maven, it will give you the paths to target/classes for your *own resources*, or the path to a jar for *other resources* (E.g. String.class). 
If you call it from a jar, it will always tell you the path of the jar file.

run from IDE:

```
/home/alexander/projects/stackoverflow/stuff/target/classes
/home/alexander/projects/stackoverflow/stuff/target/classes
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar!`
```

run from JAR:

```
/home/alexander/projects/stackoverflow/stuff/target/test-stuff-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!
/home/alexander/projects/stackoverflow/stuff/target/test-stuff-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar!
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a way to obtain class loader base path, no manually build one when case is runnning from a jar and knowing a concrete resource beforehand.

Comment: What do you mean with "class loader base path" and what with "a concrete resource"? You cann always provide getClass() from any calling class - each class should give you the jar where the class is contained. Can you provide more information e.g. an example?

Comment: I have a relative URL like "myXTypeResources/resource.csv". I just work to get the Path variable of the root folder in either Jar or src/main/resources=target/classes so I really don't mind I am running the code from jar or from file system. If "." or "/" worked on jar, that would be as easy as Path basePath = Paths.get(...getClassLoader.getResource(".").toUri())